# Laravel Promocodes FatalErrorException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm uisng laravel 5.1 Add promocodes in laravel following github ( https://github.com/Trexology/Promocodes )in that github guid completed upto Usage. Generating Promotional codes using generate method. Got this error

FatalErrorException in PromocodesServiceProvider.php line 22: Class 'Trexology\Promocodes\Facades\Promocodes' not found

Answer (score 0):

The problem which i taught,you applied code of this package but not call package name in controller.

use Promocodes;

add this line at top of your controller

Thank you